# Unable to cast LinearLayoutManager to GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, linearlayoutmanager

```
if (mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
                        ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                            @Override
                            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                                return listResultAdapter.isHeaderOrFooter(position) ? ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).getSpanCount() : 1;
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Above code is crashing saying java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager

I figured out below line is causing crash

```
((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).getSpanCount()
```

what can be the solution to avoid crash

mLayoutManager is declared as LinearLayoutManager

Comment: BTW, why do you declare `mLayoutManager ` as `LinearLayoutManager ` but use it as `GridLayoutManager `?

Comment: How is it possible?

Comment: actually i tried doing that but it was crashing when i was calling notifydataset change i tried using gridlayoutmanager setspancount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also do the class check inside `getSpanSize`:

```
public int getSpanSize(int position) {
     return mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager && listResultAdapter.isHeaderOrFooter(position) 
             ? ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).getSpanCount() : 1;
}
```